# Seeing file changes in the browser without rebuilding your project

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am a Front-end developer, currently working on a .net project. It was explained to me that some of the resources of the project are embedded and when I say some, I mean most of them. Therefor when making changes in the files, you can't see them in the browser without first re-running the project from Visual studio.

I believe you see how this is extremely annoying and frustrating to me. I am used to more dynamic way of working, even have something like livereload running to inject my styles and refresh the page when markup has changes, so I can see the changes in the browser without even switching the active window

I was wondering if there is anything even remotely close to what I am used to as a workflow for web development

Answer (score -1):

You've tagged this as MVC, so that means if the view is changed it can be reloaded without running it from Visual Studio. Further, the project just needs rebuilt if you change code. You don't have to re-run it from Visual Studio.

So, in short, you can certainly still make changes in the browser with livereoload, then move those CSS changes to the CSS files in the application, and refresh your browser. That's it.

**EDIT:** After seeing the screenshot, change that to `Content` instead of `Embedded`.

Comment: Well, I've just tried it and it's not like you said. I ran the project, opened it in the browser and the changed background of the body element to **red**. Upon refresh in nothing change. After I ran the project again, however, and then refresh the background became red as expected.

I am prettyr sure it has something to do with the css file being **embedded** or something

here is screenshot of the properties tab of the given file http://i.imgur.com/coWpSwg.png

Comment: @MetodiDeribanov: Is this an MVC application, like it's tagged, or is it a pre-compiled web forms application?

Comment: it's **MVC**, I am sure

Comment: @MetodiDeribanov, please see my edit. You'll want to stop embedding that CSS file.

Comment: I am not sure I can do that. After all I am not the only one who is working on this project. The .net guys have told me that it's not that simple. I've actually tried this myself and after I change it to Content instead of embedded it doesn't even load the file. Obviously I can't change the way the framework is used and the code it tied in. But surely there must be some sort of a workaround... Right?

Comment: @Metodi, those guys are doing something really weird if it won't even load when it's not embedded. Looks like you're literally stuck, but only because of some oddity they've introduced. This is not normal.

Answer (score -1):

Files including aspx and cshtml can be saved (most of the time) and will show changes upon page refresh. Occasionally, the file system may access the files and overwrite them. Files that are compiled upon build are not able to be changed unless a rebuild is issued.

In short terms, front-end is easily edited during run while code-behind and classes cannot.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you really want to be able to do it seamlessly, write a file watch script to run msbuild over your solution any time a file is saved. Either way - you HAVE to build it.